# Positive value of function and root

Tags: real-analysis, roots

Suppose $j,k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $1\leqslant j\leqslant k$.

The polynomial
$$
f(x)=x^{2k}-\sum_{i=0}^{k-j-1}x^i
$$
has exactly one positive root $x_0$ by Descartes' rule.

Do we also have that
$$
f(x)>0\implies x>x_0?
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x_0$ is the only positive root of $f$, it is the largest one. Then, there is no sign change of $f$ on $(x_0, \infty)$ and since $\underset{x\to + \infty}{\lim} f = + \infty$. You may indeed assert that $ x > x_0 \Rightarrow f(x) > 0 $.

However $ f(x) > 0 \Rightarrow x > x_0 $ does not generally hold. Take $j=k=1$, then $f(x) = x^2$ and $f(-1)>0$ but $-1 < 0$.

Comment: Thanks. But I guess that $f(x)>0$ and $x\geq 0$ imply $x>x_0$.

Comment: That depends on the multiplicity of $x_0$. If it is odd then yes. Otherwise, for $x\in (0,x_0)$, $f(x)>0$.

Comment: And here, $x_0$ is a simple root (hence odd), hence my statement holds, i.e. $f(x)>0$ and $x\geq 0$ indeed imply $x>x_0$.

Comment: Sure. I forgot that Descartes' rule took multiplicity into account.